# How to deal with SAML logout response in Java

Tags: java, saml, logout

Guys:

I'm adding SLO function to my project. I send logout request to my IDP and I've got logout response successfully. In my Java web inerface, I don't know how to deal with this response. How can I do if I want to know the logout is successful or not?

Hope you could give me some advises and thanks a lot in advance.

Jennings
11-18

Answer (score 0):

The [examples](https://www.samltool.com/generic_slo_res.php) show the logout response. You can look for the result in the response:

```
<samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
```

Comment: Yes, Codebrane. Thanks for your reply. But i want to know how to analyze this response in java code.